# Using height 100% to keep floating divs matching height, but paragraph inside one of them overflows

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm very new to this. Trying to create an HTML page with a simple 2 column layout. Both columns are divs inside a container div. One column is floated left, and the other is floated right. Since one column has a background color, it is important that the two divs are the same height. I've accomplished this by setting the html, body, container div, and each floated div's height to 100%. Works fine. But the one paragraph in the content (floated right div) is pretty big, and it overflows out of the div. This leads to this section at the bottom of the page where the div with the background color has no background color. I'm aware of the css overflow property, but I don't want it to overflow, I'd like the div to just be as big as the content within it. Better way to do this? Any other tips not related to teh question are also welcome. When I see all these unexpected bugs pop up, I still feel very much the beginner. Thanks, this is my first post:)

The content is just copied and pasted from allmusic.com so I had something to work with.

Here's the code:

```css
/*General
******************************************************************/


html, 
body, 
#container {
    height: 100%;
}


body {
    font-family: "Noto Sans", sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

div {
        box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    clear: both;
}

p {
    text-indent: 50px;
}

.col {
    padding: 40px;
    height: 100%;
}

/*Nav
******************************************************************/

.nav {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
}

.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    
}

.nav ul a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
}

/*Content
******************************************************************/

.content {
    float: right;
    width: 80%;
}

.content h2, .content h3 {
    text-align: right;
}

.albumCover {
    display: block;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 40%;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<!--        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" media="screen"/>-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="musics.css" media="screen"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700|Noto+Sans|Roboto+Condensed|Raleway|Titillium+Web' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <div class="col nav">
                <h3>Years</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="01TWQuadrophenia.html">1973 Quadrophenia</a></li>
                    <li><a href="02TWWhosNext.html">1971 Who's Next</a></li>
                    <li><a href="03TWTommy.html">1969 Tommy</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col content">
                <h2>Tommy</h2>
                <h3>The Who</h3>
<!--                <hr>-->
                <img class="albumCover" alt="Ray Davies Storyteller Album Cover" src="pics/twt.jpg">
                <p>The full-blown rock opera about a deaf, dumb, and blind boy that launched the band to international superstardom, written almost entirely by Pete Townshend. Hailed as a breakthrough upon its release, its critical standing has diminished somewhat in the ensuing decades because of the occasional pretensions of the concept and because of the insubstantial nature of some of the songs that functioned as little more than devices to advance the rather sketchy plot. Nonetheless, the double album has many excellent songs, including "I'm Free," "Pinball Wizard," "Sensation," "Christmas," "We're Not Gonna Take It," and the dramatic ten-minute instrumental "Underture." Though the album was slightly flawed, Townshend's ability to construct a lengthy conceptual narrative brought new possibilities to rock music. Despite the complexity of the project, he and the Who never lost sight of solid pop melodies, harmonies, and forceful instrumentation, imbuing the material with a suitably powerful grace.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bear in mind that `<p>` natively has padding & margins, try setting both to 0 on your p element css

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Use following solution instead to get the complete solution.

```
html, 
body {
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    min-height: 100%;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
.nav {
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #e6e6e6;
    position: absolute;
}
```

[JSFiddle link.](https://jsfiddle.net/v0bxkjf5/)

Comment: That works really well. Thanks! The only other thing that isn't going as expected is that while that solves the initial problem, I'm seeing that when the window size is bigger than it needs to be to fit all of the content without scrolling, there is a white space underneath everything (where the container ends). Any thoughts?